# Original error: 'POST /appium/device/open_notifications' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, adb

Device: Samsung Galaxy S9+, Android 10.0
System info: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.4', java.version: '18.0.2'
Appium version 2.0.0, Uiautomator2 version 2.10.1

The issue started to appear suddenly, no changes were made to automation setup, related automation code, app code.

The test suite is running via Jenkins pipeline on two real Android devices (Appium server instances are running on two different ports), which are calling each other, the issue happens with Device1, when it calls Device2, then the driver switches back to Device1 and trying to open the Android native notifications via:

```
ConnectAndroid.getInstance().getDriver().openNotifications();
```

Does anyone know, how to resolve this problem?

The Appium log:

```
2023-12-20 11:58:11 INFO  ActionAndroid:191 - Android: open notifications
    [38;5;0m[HTTP][0m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/1f638473-85f1-4bb9-8d01-d71689f0012d/appium/device/open_notifications[39m
    [38;5;0m[HTTP][0m {}
    [debug] [38;5;32m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@8dd7 (1f638473)][0m Calling AppiumDriver.openNotifications() with args: ["1f638473-85f1-4bb9-8d01-d71689f0012d"]
    [debug] [38;5;32m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@8dd7 (1f638473)][0m Encountered internal error running command: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'POST /appium/device/open_notifications' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running (probably crashed). Check the server log and/or the logcat output for more details
    [debug] [38;5;32m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@8dd7 (1f638473)][0m     at UIA2Proxy.command (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/jsonwp-proxy/proxy.js:355:13)
    [debug] [38;5;32m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@8dd7 (1f638473)][0m     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    [debug] [38;5;32m[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@8dd7 (1f638473)][0m     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.commands.openNotifications (/Users/iosauto/.appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/lib/commands/general.js:242:10)
    [38;5;0m[HTTP][0m <-- POST /wd/hub/session/1f638473-85f1-4bb9-8d01-d71689f0012d/appium/device/open_notifications 500 28 ms - 1037
```

After that crash the device loses connection:

```
WebDriverException catched during Android driver creation: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Device 277a222d421c7ece was not in the list of connected devices
```

Tried to restart several times the devices, the machine where the tests are running, the USB hub, where that phone is plugged in, upgrading Appium and JDK - nothing helped, the issue still reproduces each run.